# Errors compiling pdftotext.cc

Tags: pdftotext

I'm trying to compile the following code:

https://github.com/zdanozdan/pdftotext/wiki

But my ubuntu (12.04) is requiring too many dependecies, so I don't know how to achieve sucessfull compilation.

Compilation line:

> gcc -o pdftotext pdftotext.cc

The first error is:

> pdftotext.cc:9:19: fatal error: aconf.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

(sorry for my newbie question:)

Answer (score 0):

To save you a lot of time, you don't need to compile this to get it on Ubuntu. Just install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftotext
```

If you do want to compile it:

The best way to get started with a build environment is to install the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

That will get you a compiler, some development libraries, the `make` tool, and other core dependencies.

If that doesn't get what you need, the `aconf.h` error above it related to AutoConf:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

You may also need `automake`, and possibly other library dependencies for `pdftotext`. You can  often determine what's needed based on the compilation errors about "missing library" or "missing header", and use `apt-get search` to find the appropriate package. Development packages are named like `libpdf-dev` (just an example).

---

Comment: I'm also not sure that code you linked to even builds. It doesn't include a `Makefile` and I didn't dig around enough to see how it's supposed to be compiled or what its dependencies are.

Comment: Jim, thanks for your help! automake and autoconf are installed, but the same error is raising. I'm stucked...

Comment: Per my previous comment, I'm not entirely sure how to build that code. There's no `Makefile` or `configure`; it's just some source code. You could try including all the `.cc` files on the command-line. It's been a long time since I had to manually build C++ software.